# How do I include a lot of vars into Ansible roles

Tags: python, variables, yaml, roles, ansible

Considering a play setup like so:

```
- name: Provision the stage platform
  hosts: my-stage-host
  vars_files:
    - ../../env_vars/base.yml
    - ../../env_vars/stage.yml
  roles:
    - {role: 'some.ThirdpartyRole'}
    - {role: 'My.Role', name: 'app1', somevar: 'var2', dict: {'var1': 'var2'}, list: [{'var1': 'var2'}]}
    - {role: 'My.Role', name: 'app2', somevar: 'var2', dict: {'var1': 'var2'}, list: [{'var1': 'var2'}]}
```

This setup is fine and all works as expected (though I don't really like the data structure).. the problem is My.Role has a lot of role instance specific variables, lists and dicts etc, which unfortunately cannot be set in `defaults/main.yml` (As they are specific to the current role instance), and because I want to be able to use this role multiple times on one server I need isolated variables.

in a perfect world, I would be able to..

```
  roles:
    - My.Role
      include: ../../varsA.yml
```

Just like with tasks.. but from what I have read so far in the docs and forums, that's not possible...

At the moment I do have my role working with the following not ideal setup:

File: group_vars/my-host.yml

```
apps:
  name: 'something'
  someList:
    - item
    ...
  someDict:
    item: item
    itemsList: 
      - item
      ...
  name: 'somethingElse'
  someList:
    - item
    ...
  someDict:
    item: item
    itemsList: 
      - item
      ...
```

File: playbooks/my-play.yml

```
  ...
  roles:
    - some.ThirdpartyRole
    - My.Role
```

As you can see it takes all its vars from a dict defined in my group_vars, and each task within the role uses `with_items: myDict`,  this makes sublists (amongst other things) a bit of a nightmare, something like:

```
with_subelements:
  - myDict
  - subList
```

And I cant check for the existence of `mydict.subList`, I instead need empty vars defined everywhere.

I hope I've explained myself properly, I wondered if anybody had any experience with using a lot of vars in a role that they need to use multiple times in a play, or any other pointers on role/var layout.

Answer (score 11):

I have come up with a solution, it's not necessarily the "Ansible" way, but until an **include** directive is allowed for roles (as it is for tasks), this appears to be the cleanest way.

## Playbook.yml

```
- name: My Play
  hosts: my-host
  roles:
    - {"role": My.role, "vars_file": "../../vars/projectA.yml"}
    - {"role": My.role, "vars_file": "../../vars/projectB.yml"}
```

## My.role/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Load in project specific vars
  include_vars: "{{ vars_file }}"
  ...
```

[Include vars on ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/include_vars_module.html)

I saw a recent [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9498) on Ansibles Github that may affect this solution, I'm going to see if it is still the case, ill try and add to my answer once I've given things a try.